# Automatic token expire after 5 minutes Java

Tags: java, token, hsqldb

I'm trying to create a more secure way to reset a forgotten password with Java web and HSQLDB without any framework.

I created a form where the user can insert his email and if the email is in database, it will automatically send an email with a link for password reset. This link has a specific token that is created for each user when they click on the button for receiving the email. This token is inserted in the database and also the timestamp for when it is created.

**I'm trying to delete the token from the database if it reached a limit time of 5 minutes but it doesn't work.** 
Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

My **table:**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id bigint identity NOT NULL,
username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
attempts int DEFAULT 3,
state varchar(50) DEFAULT 'Active’,
reset_token uuid,
time_token TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The **tokengenerator:**

```
public class TokenGenerator {
    public static String UniqueToken() {
    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return token;

}}
```

My class **ForgotPasswordHandler.java:**

```
public class ForgotPasswordHandler {
    private static PreparedStatement ps = null;
    private static ResultSet rs = null;
    private static Connection con = DBConnectionManager.getConnection();

    //Creates a token for the user when it clicks on submit for forgot password
        public static void CreateToken (String email) {


            try
              { 

              if (con == null){
                 System.out.println("Failed connection");

              }else{
                  String token = TokenGenerator.UniqueToken();


                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                  "UPDATE user SET reset_token = ?, time_token = ? WHERE email = ?");

                ps.setString(1,token);
                ps.setTimestamp(2,new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
                ps.setString(3, email);

                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.close();


              }}
            catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(System.out);

              }
        }


       //This is where I'm having trouble to delete the actual token after 5 minutes.

        public static void DeleteToken() {

            try
              { 

              if (con == null){
                 System.out.println("Failed Connection");

              }else{



                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                  "UPDATE user SET reset_token = NULL WHERE time_token < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");


                ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.close();


              }}
            catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(System.out);

              }

        }

}
```

My Servlet **ForgotPassword.java:**

```
    public class ForgotPassword extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String host;
        private String port;
        private String email;
        private String name;
        private String pass;

        public void init() {
            // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            host = context.getInitParameter("host");
            port = context.getInitParameter("port");
            email = context.getInitParameter("email");
            name = context.getInitParameter("name");
            pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
        }



        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                //verify if emails exists in db

                String email = request.getParameter("email");

                if(!UserReset.EmailCheck(email)) {

                    String message = "This email isn't in our database";
                    request.setAttribute("message", message);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("reset.jsp").forward(request, response);   

                } else {
                    String recipient = request.getParameter("email");
                    String subject = "Your Password has been reset";



                    String token = TokenGenerator.UniqueToken();
                    ForgotPasswordHandler.CreateToken(email);
                    ForgotPasswordHandler.DeleteToken();    

                    String url = "http://localhost:8080/login/reset-password.jsp?token=" + token;
                    UserReset.RefreshState(email);

                    //Builds email message and sends it
                    String content = "Hello, please change your password in this link:" + url;
                    content += "\nObrigado!";

                    String message = "";

                    try {
                        EmailSender.sendEmail(host, port, email, name, pass,
                                recipient, subject, content);
                        message = "Please verify your email.";
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        message = "Ops, an error occured: " + ex.getMessage();
                    } finally {
                        request.setAttribute("message", message);
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("reset.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    }

                }

    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @Erwin the method that I wrote to update after 5 minutes doesn't do anything

Comment: u update it after 5 minutes and user request another password reset, or ...?

Comment: What is "more secure"?  What do you mean "doesn't work"?  Where is the log file/stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be deleting the token actively. Just record the time the token was issued, and then when the new query comes in, get the create time and check that it is within 5 minutes.

Comment: And how could I do that? Because I did record the time of the token creation, but how could I check if it is within 5 minutes?

Comment: In your login check for the token, select for the time as well, like `Select token from w where id=x and token=y and token_create_time < z` where z is the current time minus 5 minutes